# How to trigger an Custom Alert component in a different component?

Tags: reactjs, components

I made a sign in page that checks if the users email and/or password is wrong. For now I just use the default alert(). But I created my own alert component called , but I'm not sure how to make that component appear if there is an error and how to edit the elements inside to my liking based on the error.

On line 31, I indicate that I'd like to change the state of showAlert to true, and I set a time out to make the state back to false so that the alert disappears, but my code does not do that I expected. The alert always appears.

Or is this not possible and should I just go with bootstrap or some other sort of add-on? The only other way I could think of is to just copy and paste the div into each component that I want to use and just manipulate it without importing and exporting.

I am using React 17.

Heres my code, for observation:

```js
import React from 'react';
import AlertBox from '../../alert.js';

class signIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            signInEmail: '',
            signInPassword: '',
            showAlert: false,
        }
    }

    onSubmitSignIn = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: this.state.signInEmail,
                password: this.state.signInPassword
            })
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(user => {
            if(user.id !== undefined) {
                this.props.loadUser(user)
                this.props.onRouteChange('home');
            } else if(user.error !== undefined) {
                this.setState({showAlert:true})
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.setState({showAlert:false})
                }, 500)
            }
        })
        .catch(err => alert(err))
    }

    render() {
    const { onRouteChange } = this.props;
    return (
        <article className="br3 shadow-5 ba dark-gray b--black-10 mv4 w-100 w-50-m w-25-l mw8 center">
        <AlertBox isOpen={this.state.showAlert}/>
            <main className="pa4 black-80">
            
              <div className="measure">
                <fieldset id="sign_up" className="ba b--transparent ph0 mh0">
                  <legend className="f4 fw6 ph0 mh0">Sign In</legend>
                  <div className="mt3">
                    <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="email-address">Email</label>
                    <div className='input-container'>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" className="pa1 white bg-black bi bi-envelope" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M0 4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v8a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4Zm2-1a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v.217l7 4.2 7-4.2V4a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H2Zm13 2.383-4.708 2.825L15 11.105V5.383Zm-.034 6.876-5.64-3.471L8 9.583l-1.326-.795-5.64 3.47A1 1 0 0 0 2 13h12a1 1 0 0 0 .966-.741ZM1 11.105l4.708-2.897L1 5.383v5.722Z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <input 
                        className="pa2 input-reset ba b--black bg-clear-coat hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                        type="email" 
                        name="email-address"  
                        id="email-address"
                        onChange={this.onEmailChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="mv3">
                    <label className="db fw6 lh-copy f6" htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <div className='input-container'>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor" className="pa1 bi bi-key white bg-black" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                          <path d="M0 8a4 4 0 0 1 7.465-2H14a.5.5 0 0 1 .354.146l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L13 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L11 9.207l-.646.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708 0L9 9.207l-.646.647A.5.5 0 0 1 8 10h-.535A4 4 0 0 1 0 8zm4-3a3 3 0 1 0 2.712 4.285A.5.5 0 0 1 7.163 9h.63l.853-.854a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.646-.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l.646.647.793-.793-1-1h-6.63a.5.5 0 0 1-.451-.285A3 3 0 0 0 4 5z"/>
                          <path d="M4 8a1 1 0 1 1-2 0 1 1 0 0 1 2 0z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <input 
                        className="b pa2 input-reset ba b--black bg-clear-coat hover-bg-black hover-white w-100" 
                        type="password" 
                        name="password"  
                        id="password"
                        onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div>
                  <input 
                  className="b ph3 pv2 input-reset ba b--black bg-black white grow pointer f6 dib" 
                  type="submit" 
                  value="Sign in" 
                  onClick={this.onSubmitSignIn}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="lh-copy mt3">
                    <p 
                    onClick={() => onRouteChange('register')} 
                    className="f5 link dim black db">
                    Don't have an account? Register Today!
                    </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </main>
        </article>
        );
    }
}

export default signIn;
```

My Alert Component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const AlertBox = () => {
    
    return (
        <div className="alertBox pa3 bg-black ba b--white" id='let'>
          <span className='alert-text white'>Unable to sign in</span>
        </div>
        );
    
}

export default AlertBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Context` provided at a higher level than both components. You can generally just put the context in your top level component.

As the value for the context, you can pass in some state of that top level component. That way you can trigger a rerender with the `setState` function.

```
export const AlertContext = createContext([]);

export default function App() {
  const alertState = useState(false);
  return (
    <AlertContext.Provider value={alertState}>
      <ToggleAlert />
      <Alert />
    </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Notice how I did not deconstruct the return value of `useState` into `[alertState, setAlertState]`.

In both components you can call `useContext` to get the higher level state.

```
export default function Alert() {
  const [alertState] = useContext(AlertContext);
  return alertState ? <h1>Alert!</h1> : null;
}
```

```
export default function ToggleAlert() {
  const [_, setAlertState] = useContext(AlertContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setAlertState(true)}>Show Alert</button>
      <button onClick={() => setAlertState(false)}>Hide Alert</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nv3cv2?file=App.tsx

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had doubted that there may have been a way, but this will help me to get started and do more research since I don't know much of context or useState. And also wondering how this will work inside a class rather than a function but I will dive more into this.